# splunk query based on log stdout

Tags: select, logging, splunk

I cannot think of how to query a splunk. I have log "Waiting for changelog lock.." and now I need to select all occurrences if in 10 minutes time period, starting from after this is printed, there is no log saying "Successfully acquired change log lock". This does not work, as it checks if same log contains it: `index="[there goes my index]" | spath log | search NOT log="*Successfully acquired change log lock*" AND log='Waiting for changelog lock..' earliest=-10m@m latest=now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that the current query expects one field to contain two different values, which will never work.  Instead, use `OR` and then pick off the most recent event.  If it's "Successfully..." then all is well; otherwise, it's a problem.

```
index="[there goes my index]" earliest=-10m@m latest=now
| spath log 
| search NOT log="*Successfully acquired change log lock*" OR log='Waiting for changelog lock..' 
| dedup log
| where log="Waiting for changelog lock"
```

Comment: this one somehow did not work, but I have waited for 5min and LockException is thrown. So I can easy use  spath log | search log="****LockException****" :)